# Overriding woocommerce template (header and footer) on a child theme

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I'm using a WordPress Sydney theme (the free version). I've created a child theme to customize and tailor it to my needs. I installed woocommerce plugin and I'm trying to make a shop out of this website. All is good and I'm almost done with it, but I encountered a problem.

Woocommerce plugin template pages (for example */templates/archive-product.php*) are using `<?php get_header('shop'); ?>` and loading the parent themes *header.php* and it's CSS and all the styling and header modifications are made on the child theme.

I'm new to this WordPress theme thing, maybe I don't understand fully how it works. Maybe someone knows how do I fix this on my child theme? Or maybe there is some kind of a work around?

Comment: If you put a `header-shop.php` in your theme then WordPress will use that. Any custom styles will need to be enqueued from your child theme.

Comment: I understand that. I have an edited header.php + styles.css in my child theme and the rest of the pages use those, but woocommerce page's use the parent theme's header / footer and doesn't load child themes css.

Comment: Is your parent theme overriding WooCommerce templates such as `single-product.php`? That has a [`get_header('shop')`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/2.6.13/templates/single-product.php#L23) line, so if you have a `header-shop.php` that will be used unless your parent theme has overridden that template and calling for a different header. Secondly, WooCommerce doesn't automatically load the child theme's CSS, you need to enqueue that on your own, see [`wp_emqueue_style()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/)

Comment: My child theme is overiding the templates abd the header is loaded as it should now. I had the templates in the wrong folder. I have css load in my child theme's functions.php "add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', '/styles.css', 999 );"